# Neural Network Using ReLU Activation Function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, relu

I am trying to use a neural network to predict the price of houses. Here is what the top of the dataset looks like:

```
    Price   Beds    SqFt    Built   Garage  FullBaths   HalfBaths   LotSqFt
    485000  3       2336    2004    2       2.0          1.0        2178.0
    430000  4       2106    2005    2       2.0          1.0        2178.0
    445000  3       1410    1999    1       2.0          0.0        3049.0

...
```

I am trying to use the ReLU activation function, but my accuracy is zero even after 100 epochs. Am I missing something here?

```
X = dataset[:,1:8] #predictor variables
Y = dataset[:,0] #sell price

#Normalize data
from sklearn import preprocessing
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_scale

#Split Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)
print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape)
```

- Implement Model

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential(
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)[1]
## Output: 3/3 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -5698781.5000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accuracy is 0 because you forgot to add an output layer, so your loss is not computed properly. In addition to this, accuracy is not a relevant metric since you are doing regression and not classification.

You need to modify your model like this:

```
model = Sequential(
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)),
    Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Also, in your model.compile() you have to modify your loss to be "`mse`" instead of "`binary_crossentropy`", since you are doing regression and not classification.

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As well you are solving a regresion problem,

so you should use mean square as loss function...

and also you are trying to predict one values, so you should add one more layer to output that value.

Comment: another layer to output the value? How would I do that?

Comment: As mention before, the last layer will be, tf.keras.layers.Dense(1), one value  as output, the activation is lineal. also show as the answer posted above by Timbus